# var_dump e print_r Not Yet Implemented

Tags: php

Eu fui debugar uma instância de `DOMAttr` com `var_dump` e `print_r` e ocorreu o seguinte erro:

Exemplo:

```
print_r($domnode);
```

Saída:

```
Not yet implemented
```

Ao invés de mostrar os dados do `objeto`, foi me retornado essa mensagem.

O que significa isso?

Comment: É pegadinha do malandro?

Comment: Aqui -> https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61858

Comment: Qual versão do php está usando?

Answer (score 4):

Eu *acho* que isso quer dizer que o objeto em questão não implementa um suposto método interno que determina como será a saída desse tipo de objeto nessas funções. Algo como um `toString` interno.

---

Segundo um comentário no [bug report que o Bacco encontrou](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61858), o que faltaria ser implementado seria o método `DomAttr->schemaTypeInfo`.

Comment: As classes da `Dom` são as únicas que retornam a saída "(Ommited content)"